# How to show slider image titles as bootstrap 4 slider caption

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using understrap theme (https://understrap.com/) which uses bootstrap with wordpress. I am trying to show some captions on the slider images. I believe I  need to add this code as per Bootstrap 4 documentation:

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
   <h5>...</h5>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Now I am not sure how can I pull title of the images to show in the Heading area. I believe I can just remove the paragraph part. 
When I add title to the slideshow images, it currently shows up next to the images without any tags. I thought may be I could add html as input so I added

Image Title

instead of just text in the field but it does not work. Right now I see, titles floating in the code like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item">Floating Title
<img width="1400" height="637" src="http://localhost/WebTest1/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/test-5.jpg" class="image wp-image-62  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" srcset="http://localhost/WebTest1/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/test-5.jpg 1400w, http://localhost/WebTest1/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/test-5-300x137.jpg 300w, http://localhost/WebTest1/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/test-5-768x349.jpg 768w, http://localhost/WebTest1/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/test-5-1024x466.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1400px) 100vw, 1400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the slider code as according to bootstrap 4.0 guideline as given in reference link.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: That is what I followed and added the code. I see the html showing at the right place on the slide. Now my question is how to get the slide image titles to show in there?